# Using Javascript - How to Click a Submit Button that has No ID, Value or Name

Tags: javascript

How can I use javascript to "click" a button that has no id, value, class or name?

The relevant code for the button is:

```
<div class="classname anotherclassname" title="">
    <div>
        <button type="submit"><i class="anotherclass anotherclassname"></i>ImAButton</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd give an example of what I have so far, as I know that is simply good etiquette here on stackoverflow, but I don't even know where to start.  The only way I presently know how to use javascript to click a button is using this:

```
document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();
```

And that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Is there only the one submit button on the DOM ?

Comment: what is the reason for no name and id

Comment: If it is the only submit-button on the page, you could select it with  `document.querySelectorAll("button[type='submit'])`

Comment: <button type="submit" onclick="yourFunction()">
create a functionin your script then

Comment: @PSR I don't know, I'm building a bot using uBot and the page I'm trying to automate the submission of the button on has it setup that way.

Comment: Place the mouse pointer above the element, and click the left button. That's how you click a submit button? To programatically send the form, use `form.submit()`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();`

Comment: I would say why click the button? Submit the form

Comment: @epascarello Well now I feel dumb. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are okay with only supporting modern browsers and IE8 and above, then you could use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) to select the element. Given that the button is the only button of type submit on the page, you could do:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button[type='submit']")[0].click();
```

querySelectorAll takes any valid CSS-selector (IE8 only support CSS2 selectors). So if you need to make the selection more specific, you could just make the selector more specific as you would with any CSS-selector. Something like this for example:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".classname button[type='submit'"])[0].click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all button on page using

```
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
```

may fire a click on the first button.